# How to use my own functions with CMake for OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am using OpenCV 2.3 on Windows 7 32 bits with Visual C++ 2010.
My CMakeLists file looks like that:

```
SET( PROJECT_NAME Tennis_tracking )
PROJECT( ${PROJECT_NAME} )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( histogram histogram.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( histogram ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

For example I'd like to create a custom function "getImageHistogram" for example (which already exists in OpenCV) that will be used by main.cpp. The header and main files are done, how do I link those in my CMakeLists?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using C++ you can define this function within another (custom) namespace and call it as `custom::getImageHistogram()`.

And for the CMake part, there's nothing special to be done since you are already adding that file to the build process:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
```